# Does the presence of an outlier increase the probability that another outlier will also be present on the same observation?

Tags: outliers, mathematical-statistics

****Edit:** (10/26/13) More clear (hopefully) mini-rewrites added at the bottom**

***I'm asking this from a theoretical/general standpoint - not one that applies to a specific use case.***

I was thinking about this today:

**Assuming the data does not contain any measurement errors, if you're looking at a specific observation in your data and one of the measurements you recorded contains what could be considered an outlier, does this increase the probability (above that of the rest of the observations that do not contained measured outliers) that the same observation will contain another outlier in another measurement?**

***For my answer I'm looking for some sort of theorem, principle, etc. that states what I'm trying to communicate here much more elegantly.  For clearer explanations see Gino and Behacad's answers.***

Example:

Let's say you're measuring the height and circumference of a certain type of plant.  Each observation corresponds to 1 plant (you're only doing this once).

For height, you measure:

```
Obs 1  |   10 cm
Obs 2  |   9 cm
Obs 3  |   11 cm
Obs 4  |   22 cm
Obs 5  |   10 cm
Obs 6  |   9 cm
Obs 7  |   11 cm
Obs 8  |   10 cm
Obs 9  |   11 cm
Obs 10  |   9 cm
Obs 11  |   11 cm
Obs 12  |   10 cm
Obs 13  |   9 cm
Obs 14  |   10 cm
```

Since observation 4 contains what could be considered an outlier from the rest of the data, would the probability increase that measured circumference also contains an outlier for observation #4?

I understand my example may be too idealistic but I think it gets the point across...just change the measurements to anything.

## ***Edited in attempts to make more clear:***

(10/26/13)

**Version 1 Attempt of Abbreviated Question:**

> In nature and in general, is there a tendency (even a weak one) that
> the ***probability is greater*** that the "degree of variance from the
> mean in any attribute(s) of an observation" will be *similar* to the
> "degree of variance from the mean in any other* specific attribute of
> that same observation" ***in comparison to the probability*** that it
> will INSTEAD be *more similar* to the "degree of variance from the
> mean in that same* specific attribute of *any other observation*."

** next to a word means I was pairing what they reference.

"Quotes" used above mean nothing and are used simply to help section parts together/off for clarity.*

**Version 2 Attempt of Abbreviated Question:**

> In nature and in general, is variance from the mean across
> observations for one attribute¹ correlated (even with *extremely*
> loose correlation) to the variance from the mean across observations for all
> attributes¹?

*¹Attribute meaning measurement, quality, presence-of-either of these, and/or nearly anything else that the word "attribute" could even slightly represent as a word.  Include all synonyms of the word "attribute" as well.*

Comment: Unless you stipulate a definite probability model for your data and also define--in a specific and operational way--what "outlier" might mean, this question will not be answerable.

Comment: I did hesitate to use the word "outlier" as I didn't want to really throw a label (and one that is somewhat subjective) onto what I'm trying to explain - and especially one that may mislead.  When you say a "definite probability model" could you elaborate?  I'm open to any critiques of how I asked the question as I don't feel I did the best job explaining what I'm trying to ask.

Comment: If the variables are correlated in the tails, then you will have such tendency. However, since outliers are rare, there is no realistic empirical way to show such 'tail dependency'.

Comment: I hardly know where to begin. Let's start with getting some context for the question and understanding the meanings of the terms you use. Precisely what do you mean by the "probability" of an outlier? Are you supposing a sequential experiment in which the chance of an "outlier" changes over time? If so, what is your model for this? Do you perhaps mean your *estimated* probability of an outlier? If the latter, what was your initial estimated probability (or basis to assess a *change* in probability)? How are you estimating the probability?  How are you identifying "outliers"?

Comment: @whuber Whuber, I tried to answer each of your questions the best I can in the following text.  Each of my answers is paired with a # I assigned to your question.  The #s were assigned sequentially.

Comment: First off, it may be best to think of this in terms of "amount of variance" - Behacad's answer may help.

Comment: Answers: 

1) The likelihood that a specific measurement for a specific observation would be considered an outlier.  Again, it may be best to think of this in terms of "amount of variance" instead of "outlier".

2) We can add in the dimension of time, but I'm moreso looking for a general type of response that could be applicable to nearly any situation whether it be sequential or not.

3) See previous answer, I'm not sure it matters if it's sequential or not as I'm looking for a more general response.

Comment: 4)  Well it's more a comparison. However, you could assume that we have not actually determined a specific probability yet and thus it would be estimated.  5)  It should not matter I would think as I'm only interested in the comparison of the probability of (Group A, Observations that contain an outlier & Group B, Observations that do not contain an outlier).  6)  I was probably using the term "outliers" too loosely...the other answers may help clarify.  Once again, I'm interested in the comparison of probability (is it safe to assume its greater than the other?) - not an exact quantification.

Comment: I answered the last two questions as 1 question by the way.  Also, thanks for your input whuber!

Comment: If the variables are independent, then no. If they're dependent, it depends on the form of dependence and how that interacts with your definition of what makes an outlier.

Comment: @Glen_b The main theme of the question is essentially that all variables are dependent to -some degree- no matter how small that degree is.  Kind of like the "a butterfly causing a hurricane" zen outlook.  In reality, I feel like categorizing things as such (independent, dependent) is actually, when you think deeply about it, somewhat of a misnomer...but the assumption is necessary in order to perform certain desired calculations.

Comment: If they're dependent, it's almost certain to change the probability, but it may be up or down and it may be a lot or a little; we can't say much of anything in the general case.

Comment: @Glen_b yes, if they're "dependent"...I may not be communicating my point very well.  The two other answers may help to clarify.

Comment: It's perfectly possible to have a form of dependence that *doesn't* change the probability of an outlier. It's perfectly possible to have a form of dependence that doesn't change the variance.

Comment: @Glen_b Exactly.  However, I already admit in my question all outcomes are obviously ___possible____.   However, I'm wondering if there is something in the way nature/the universe works whereby an observation containing a measurement/etc. that is an "outlier"/"has-a-certain-amount-of variance-away-from-the-mean-to-where-it-could-potentially-'stand-out'" (this is obviously subjective...but shouldn't matter) has a higher probability (IN GENERAL - and the keyword here is "probability") of having another measurement/quality that also shares this same "attribute" in comparison to obsv that don't.

Comment: @glen_b I attempted to add some better explanations at the bottom of my question, let me know if they help at all

Comment: It's not really possible to generalize in such a way (outside of something like 'sometimes'); it would require us to have a special kind of highly comprehensive knowledge that we don't possess. (As Dr Lanning's hologram said in a movie, "*You must ask the right questions.*")

Comment: @Glen_b 1) It's not possible to prove this generalization as a mathematical law: __I (at least now) completely agree__.  It's not "possible to generalize in such a way": __I disagree__ - one can choose to throw labels onto an idea/concept and believe it is true despite the ability for said idea/concept to be empirically proven.  I know what I'm asking is nearly (if not completely) impossible to prove, but this is StackExchange (most intelligent people I've ever encountered for the section they mostly represent) - so I had a glimmer of hope. Just pointing me to any relevant text is welcome too.

Comment: Glen, also, if you have any advice on how to make my question more clear then I'm more than happy to incorporate it in...admittedly I'm not the best at communicating things and thus may need help following your advice "You must ask the right questions." without actually changing what I'm asking.

Comment: I can't tell what you really need to ask. If I had better advice, you can be completely certain I'd let you know. And your assertion in your first response of the two above this one (the thing that you believe to be true) -- you're welcome to provide evidence of that, or some logical argument for it. In fact, I recommend you do, because it will likely reveal something important (such as an unstated assumption you have).

Comment: @glen_b I believe both/all parts of the comment/assertion to be...well true...- but that is only "me."  Otherwise I wouldn't of written them :)  I think you are referencing the part where I say ".... It's not 'possible to generalize in such a way': I disagree - one can...." though.  In this, I'm not necessarily stating a mathematical/logical argument here...but more-so a semantic one, ha.  One can generalize (you could use the word believe as a synonym here) anything they want.  It's just that not everything everyone "generalizes" (or believes) is true.

Comment: ^Essentially I was trying to illustrate that because you (even though you have massive amount of credibility) say that this cannot be proven - or even if it actually is completely and irrevocably impossible to prove - it does not actually affect whether or not it __actually is true__.  It merely affects our perceived __likelihood__ that it is true (not to get too deep, but not even the simplest "laws" of science are 100%). It's the same concept as having faith in religion.  It is not proven, but people still believe as if it were true, because no one can really and empirically prove otherwise.

Comment: ^Lol have to clarify that above and I'm getting way off topic.  Basically, anything that humans believe is always true (even if it's gravity) is only our perception of such.  However when you solidly prove something (like π, gravity, or the Pythagorean theorum) the likelihood it is true may as well be 100% and its easier/makes more sense to just assume it is than taking into consideration the .00000001% chance it isn't.  Back on topic though, I obviously can't prove it to be true or not true..but I keep feeling the tendency exists. I'm looking for any evidence that tilts my opinion either way.

Comment: I suggest we take it up in Ten Fold

Comment: The new questions are still puzzling. Version 2 looks most like "are variables are general correlated?" to which an empirical answer is simply yes. But the precise sense remains elusive. "Variance" and "correlation" have existing statistical meanings as _collective_ properties of samples or populations; Taal seems to be using them to refer to _individual_ observations and/or as if variance were a word that should just be read as another word for variation. Regarding all definitions as arguable much reduces the scope for definite statements. We still need a definition for probability.

Comment: Should be "are variables in general correlated?"

Comment: @NickCox  Yes, admittedly version 2 was pretty bad and I worried someone would interpret it exactly as you just did...which really is my fault. What did you think of the first version?...or I'm assuming that's where your request for clarification on my "taal jargon" comes from, heh - although I don't feel my use of the words is too off.  I will try to correct this and further clarify - join ten fold.  I will say though that my use of the word "probability" means (as defined by Google) "the extent to which something is probable; the likelihood of something happening or being the case." ..more..

Comment: As for an exact probability (or likelihood) it doesnt matter - all I'm interested in is if the probability is greater for an observation that has a data point that (i'll try some different words) is "uncommon in degree or intensity in comparison to other data points of the measurement for all observations".  I can't quantify this - as it doesn't actually matter.  If an observation has a data point with this quality, is there a greater chance (ill quantify "chance" here arbitrary as 4:10 odds) that it will have other data points with the same quality in comparison to obsv with datap without...

Comment: ^...this quality. So observations with a datapoint with this quality have a (completely made up quantifcation for example) 4 times out of 10 tries chance of having another datapoint from another of any measurement with this "outlier-ish" quality in comparison to observations that don't have any datapoints that are "uncommon in degree or intensity in comparison to other data points of the measurement for all observations."  So for these "normal" observations with "average" (loosely used) datapoints for seemingly all of their datapoints their chances of having a datapoint is 3 out of 10....

Comment: ^...assume you looked at all datapoints except for one just for this example's and explanation of my conjecture's sake.

Comment: On CV we can try to deal with definite technical questions. You seem to want to ask much looser philosophical questions. CV isn't a good forum for that. I can't see that we are going to make things much clearer for you. The definition of probability as the extent to which something is probable unfortunately does not help. People want you to give a formal statement defining probability _mathematically_ for your example; if you don't want to do that, discussion here remains very difficult.

Comment: @NickCox I'm only looking for this: "Is this probability greater than that probability?"  I'll join ten fold in a second - we can chat there instead of me spamming comments here...heh.

Comment: Overlapping here, but the same point about definition of probability applies to invocations of "chance". I don't see that I am helping you, but I tried.

Comment: @NickCox Lol, lets just chat in Ten Fold - this question has been bugging my mind for like the past week...not that I'm assuming it will be solved...just a point in the right direction or things like your last comment which are helpful :)

Comment: Yeah, give me some time and I'll try to study more deeply the responses by you and glen in the comments and attempt a rewrite or (at) you/glen with a comment hopefully where I feel I've read enough and confidently feel we're on the same page.  I do appreciate your input though.

Comment: My biggest question is: "outlier on what"? If we specify a certain field (e.g., health), then I think we can find an answer. If it is just in general, then perhaps not. There are literally an infinite amount of variables associated with any observation. Imagine a study in which you measure a person's intelligence, the length of their toenails, how many particles are in the underwear they are wearing, and the number of letters in the first name of their great great great great grandmother. Being an outlier on any of these might not mean they will be on anything else...Thoughts?

Comment: @Behacad #1 I feel very alone now Behacad!  #2 You fell into the example trap #3 How does one specify what is contained in a certain field?...that's assuming somewhat obvious dependency first - I am assuming all things are dependent on some level (and this is, yes very esoteric) #4 This is almost like a philosophical question - perhaps I should ask it over there? #5 I view this as a tendency - meaning it won't always happen...but a pattern is recognizable if you're able to zoom out enough. #6 Also interested in other thoughts you have tho as you're the only other one who understands the most.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**NARROW VIEW 1**
A narrow view of this question (since the other answers and comments I believe have covered adequately various general approaches) is "Assume two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are dependent. Does the variance of $X$ conditional on $Y$ is a function of the variance of $Y$?

To take refuge in the normal distribution, if both $X$ and $Y$ are normal and dependent, denote $\sigma^2_x$, $\sigma^2_y$, $\sigma_{xy}$ their unconditional variances and their covariance respectively. Then

$$\operatorname {Var}(X\mid Y) = \sigma^2_x-\frac {\sigma_{xy}^2}{\sigma^2_y} $$

which is increasing in $\sigma^2_y$. Note that the direction of their covariance (positive/negative) doesn't matter.

But also, note that the conditional variance is *lower* than the unconditional variance...

**NARROW VIEW 2**
A 2nd narrow view of the matter is: consider pairs of random variables $(X_i,Y_i),\; i=1,...,n$, and $\sigma^2_x(i)$ and $\sigma^2_y(i)$ their unconditional variances. Assume that for some indices $k,j \in [1,...,n]$, we have $\sigma^2_y(k) > \sigma^2_y(j), \forall j\neq k$.
Should we "expect" that $\sigma^2_x(k) > \sigma^2_x(j), \forall j\neq k$ also?
This formalization of the OP's question requires from us to consider directly the dependence of each $(X_i,Y_i)$ on a common source, say a vector of random variables $\mathbf Z_i$,  So we have

$$X_i = h_i(\mathbf Z_i),\;\; Y_i = g_i(\mathbf Z_i)$$

Then we ask "does (or when)
$$ \operatorname {Var}[g_k(\mathbf Z_k)]>\operatorname {Var}[g_j(\mathbf Z_j)] \Rightarrow ? \operatorname {Var}[h_k(\mathbf Z_k)]>\operatorname {Var}[h_j(\mathbf Z_j)],\; \forall j\neq k$$

To be able to tell something about such an inequality, it must be the case that at least some of the variables that appear in $Z_j$, must also appear in the other $Z_i$'s: then as a necessary condition, we do not only require that the elements of each pair of $(X_i,Y_i)$ rv's are dependent -we require also that the pairs are dependent between them: good-bye i.i.d samples...

Comment: @Alecos_Papadopoulos Not gonna lie, this is a SICK answer - and the type I've genuinely been looking for - as I can't write a sort of proof like that.  But it comes from you with unintended consequences.  I've actually noticed that as I explain this to anyone I know - those who are actually less mathematically inclined surprisingly understand it and agree with it in comparison to those who do - as those who are mathematically inclined can't help but put generalized labels on things as a matter of habit (afterall, labels do make things much easier and efficient - the problem is they ...cont..

Comment: ..cont.. also introduce artificiality.  Before I go deeper, I want to clarify I'm speaking of the idea of an "independent variable."  No variable is __truly "indepedent"__ in nature/the universe- however we must assume some if not most are "indepedent" because it's not feasible to incorporate all potential permutations and level of complexity of thus in a manner that is practical in reality, we must actually make this assumption.

Comment: The last part "good-bye i.i.d samples..." - yes - without sarcasm this time though - truly indeed :)  __Goodbye i.i.d samples.  You don't exist.__  Keep in mind though, I'd still say there's a greater tendency for my conjecture to appear or manifest itself (but not a greater one for it to be true...as it's always true as a tendency across nature/universe) the more the dependence between variables is obvious/intense.

Comment: There has been a time where Science was subsumed in Philosophy. In the old days, people instinctively felt that "everything is connected to everything else", and built their attempts to understand the world around this principle, and trying to make it operational. Rationalism emerged because the human race proved slow and sloppy in this herculean task: and rationalism means narrowing your view in order to obtain applicable results. It is an ugly compromise, I know, but it was the price to pay in order for the human race to rule the world -a world it fundamentally misunderstands.

Comment: Exactly.  Although you don't fully admit above to the first concept that "everything is connected to everything else," you do at least insinuate it :)  I only say this because you agree with me, as I've said in your comments and a few others I just made that we put these labels for the sake of __practicality__.  Thus, simply by process of elimination I'm presuming you do agree - but I'd be curious as to your true opinion, because if so...it looks like we have a proof pending one assumes there is some connection between everything.  To me, I'm not sure how that's not true - but can't prove it.

Comment: There is irony in this perceived practicality one gains by "rationalism" though.  You see, pending one assumes everything is connected in some way (which intuitively and at first glance allow "for the human race to rule the world" or really makes things more practical)....this conjecture, when assumed as a weak tendency, has very practical applications.  Think about machine learning pending certain computational resources on massive amounts of data - you program the machine to investigate an observation with an outlier for other strange characteristics for greater efficiecy.

Comment: And really, this concept is already used in government for more intelligent law enforcement for example and a variety of other fields that one could make analogous to "finding a needle in a haystack" in the situation where the resources for combing through EVERYTHING just do not exist.

Comment: Readers whose first language is not informal American may need to consult http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/sick or some other source to understand that "SICK" is intended positively. Localised slang is better avoided on international sites; that's not to say that we should all write pompously, far from it, but to flag that's there is more risk of slang being understood.

Comment: ^^ Very good point & thank you for pointing that out.  I wish I thought about that before.  Sadly, both of these comments are below the comment fold and I frustratingly can't edit that now...agh.

Answer (score 9):

It might be true for your example (or it might not—plant No. 4 could be an etiolated seedling elongating its stem in a hunt for light without expanding its girth), but it's a matter of prior botanical knowledge rather than any general statistical law. It's not hard to construct counter-examples: someone who's an outlier on hours per week spent exercising is less likely to be an outlier on blood pressure. Any type of dependence is possible in principle—Chaos Theory doesn't say the butterfly that flaps its wings hardest causes the biggest hurricane (I don't know what Zen Buddhism says). A general theory that ranges over all measurements anyone might want to make on all kinds of things is going to be elusive.

If you consider a world with a well-defined set of objects, $a_1, a_2, \ldots$, & a well-defined set of measurements we can make on each object, $x_{11}, x_{12}, \ldots, x_{21}, x_{22}\ldots$, then your question could perhaps be framed in an answerable way ("Pick $n$ objects at random from the $a$s, pick two measurements at random from the $x$s, ..."); for our world I don't see how it can be.

Comment: Yes, I agree my example was pretty idealistic, and yes, it is easy to construct counter examples.  Your last sentance sums it up quite well...in that it'd be elusive. There's some weird part of my intuition that keeps wanting to believe that although counter examples are a definite possibility....despite that...is there a higher -probability- as told by the laws of nature that goes up when one measurement is considered far enough away from the mean/an "outlier"?

Comment: It's interesting to think about.  Although I have no idea how one would g about proving this or disproving this.  To me at least, some sort of empirical quantification with fancy variables either way would be very interesting.

Comment: I've no idea how one could even formulate the notion in such a way that it *could* be empirically proved or disproved. Nor of in what circumstances it might be rational to allow it to over-ride particular prior knowledge.

Comment: It would just be a theory or a conjecture really.  I never said that I would let this over run prior knowledge - that would be silly.  There are certain cases where this notion could be helpful though...such as trying to understand, at a qualitiative (not quantitative) level, certain relationships between your measurements/data (that you did not already know) at a deeper level.  A deeper understanding would most likely help in some way one to solve whatever question they need answered or whatever model the are trying to create.

Comment: Meant to add this in hindsight: I admit in my question (correct me if I'm wrong) that the __possibility__ of what goes against my "conjecture" here is obviously always true.  However, I'm not asking about __possibility__, I'm asking about __probability__.  Citing a counter-example does nothing to illustrate probability - and more specifically only the presence  of a probability that is greater than observations that do not contain this "degree of variance/variance/outlier/difference/etc." quality I'm trying to describe.

Comment: It's a counter-example only to the idea that, for any given probability model of the dependence between two measurements, an individual's being extreme in one increases the probability of its being extreme in the other. @Glen pointed out that that isn't necessarily the case, & I was only trying to show that its not implausible in practice that it isn't. (I'm not saying it isn't obvious, or that you thought otherwise, but it's worth pointing out in response to your question as originally written.)

Comment: As I've tried to say, your conjecture that measurements on things are generally correlated in a particular way is too vaguely specified to be able to talk about it in terms of probability. You'd have to specify the universe of "measurements" & of "things" you're interested in.

Comment: Counter-examples are indeed not evidence against a general probability. Also, I think your answer actually supports the hypothesis that being an outlier on one variable increases odds of being an outlier on other variables. Indeed, an outlier on hours per week spent exercising is MORE likely to be an outlier on blood pressure (i.e., having lower blood pressure).

Comment: @Behacad: Blood pressure doesn't go down more & more as you exercise more & more - someone who exercises a lot is especially likely to have bp in the normal range (unless we're considering a terribly unfit population where hypertension is the norm). More importantly, would you care to define what this "general probability" in fact means?

Comment: Citing a few counter-examples of anything does not offer evidence regarding any probability, unless that probability is posited to be 100% or 0%. If I am wondering whether boys are more likely to be taller than girls, I don't think you citing three examples in which particular girls are taller than particular boys is very helpful. I don't know what the answer to this question is,  but I don't think this answer is particularly compelling. It might be, but may need a bit more editing.

Comment: @Becahad: The point's simply that *there are* both counter-examples and examples, like the physical dimensions of Gino's giants. We could take a stab at defining a population of children to answer your question whether boys are more likely to be taller than girls, but we'd be at a loss to do so for Taal's question.

Comment: @Scortchi First off, Behacad completely understands my question (relievingly so actually - as I'm a bit baffled by the majority of the responses, lol).  Based upon this, I'm (haha) going to conject here that there's a bit higher probability that he possesses another/some other trait(s)(or whatever) that is also quite a bit different from the average of whatever this/these is/are of all the others attempting to answer my question here....despite my sample size being quite low.  I actually believe it's a different type/level of intuition :)

Comment: @Scortchi Any specific example by those here who "get it" has been used with the assumption that any reader will understand the example is only an attempt to illustrate a small (and obvious) part of the point instead of one that is stating this always exists across all variables and in all observations in a measurable way.  The correct way to think about this is as a __weak tendency__ of nature - not something that occurs as often as it seems many believe it does.  You're second paragraph also is an attempt at another example - theorums are not proven with specific examples.

Comment: Despite the votes, and appreciation of the actual awesome type of discussion I was hoping for in the comments here....I cannot at all even consider awarding the bounty here unfortunately....and that's at no offense - but...lol I think the only person who may seem to understand my frustration here is Behacad.

Comment: I clearly lack the type/level of intuition needed to understand what's meant by a weak tendency of nature that doesn't exist in a measurable way. I'll stick to my statistical last & leave the more highly-evolved souls to contemplate it in peace.

Comment: @Scortchi Check out Alecos's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to say yes. Of course something being an outlier on one measure does not necessarily mean it will be an outlier on other measures, but I think it certainly increases the odds. In essence, I think anything being unusual in one way is more likely to be unusual in other ways. This is perhaps the result of different variables being correlated in all kinds of ways. So if one is "extreme", this will also correlate with other factors that might also be in the extreme range.

I hope someone can provide a better answer with some empirical evidence. Perhaps we can look at this from the multivariate outlier perspective. In my experience, individuals who are outliers on one variable are often outliers on many other variables as well, contributing to multivariate outlierness.

Take this answer with a grain of salt since it depends on how we define an outlier and such, but I think in general it makes sense.

Comment: You've definitely added to my question and also helped to refine it  - I was also mostly thinking about this in terms of individuals/choices/personality traits/etc. but I don't think that it stops there.  I suppose I'm looking for some sort of theorem or principle that attempts to explain this elegantly. Michael Mayer did have a good response though.

Answer (score 2):

I will try to reply using empirical evidence. Let's assume you are measuring the heights in a men sample. In this case, the outlier will be represented by a very tall men (a giant). It is very likely this men will represent an outlier also for other variables like for instance shoe size or arms lengths and so on.
Other case, you are measuring financial performance of US Public company. An outlier will be a very successful company with a sales growth twice the industry average. Very likely the same company will be an outlier in respect of any measure of profitability or stock price appreciation. In a nut shell, I am incline to think something behaving exceptionally out of the norm will tend to conserve this property across different manifestations. Is there a theorem that disprove this theory?

Comment: Yes, another good representation of what I'm trying to communicate - and yes also looking for a theorum that speaks about this as my ultimate question (I need to edit the original actually). As another example, I was thinking about the personalities/etc. of girls that "dye their hair blue."  This is not a very usual thing to do where I live, so I'm thinking it would be safe to assume there is a higher probability (in comparison to girls that didn't have an outlier as such...and yes I'm controlling the experiment here a bit) that this girl will also have other "outlier-ish" characteristics.

Comment: The "sales growth" example is somewhat flawed - many extremely high sales growth companies are unprofitable (see: Amazon). But more importantly, all of your examples are dependent on each other. Then what you're describing isn't a property of "outlier-ness" but on the value itself. Saying a tall person is likely to have high values for characteristics associated with height is just correlation.

Comment: @EpiGrad The conjecture is that this is a __weak tendency__ for a __probability__ to be higher (and the degree of "higher" may even be quite small...but still exist in nature.  (I'm realizing I really should probably update the question a bit now).  I believe the poster here understood this and assumed, like I did, that people wouldn't interpret the examples in the fashion that this is true when the variables are ONLY "dependent" on each other in such an obvious way.  Basically, one must agree that everything in the universe is dependently related to everything else - and this really is true.

Comment: **TRUE** "independent" variables simply do not exist - really think about that.  We simply assume and throw the label onto them that they are "independent" to be able to use methods that have been created in statistics in a practical manner.

Comment: @Taal Given I've encountered variables that are about as independent as they come (seriously, once found a relative risk of 1.00 with a 95% confidence interval from 0.99 to 1.01), I'm going to have to suggest "Citation Needed". And if the poster, and you, aren't relying on variables that are only dependent in obvious ways, I'd suggest finding concrete examples of that, rather than simply asserting they exist.

Answer (score 2):

Outliers are a reflection of an unknown/unspecified external factor. If there is a relationship between two series then there would be an increased probability that both series would be affected. My answer to your question is "yes" since there may be a relationship between the two series.

Comment: I like the first sentence in your answer alot.  When you say "if there is a relationship between two series"...it makes me strongly believe you are, like many others have (but not as intensly as they have), jumping ahead a slight bit from where I'm starting - which does not look for a relationship before assuming the conjecture is true.  The conjecture is actually the tool in which one would use to potentially discover new relationships - it comes before assuming any relationships besides the fact that all the observations (hate that word here actually) - are the same..cont..

Comment: ...cont...example: All the observations are measuring or looking at something involving blades of grass.  And actually - really - to be honest it assumings every things/measurement/idea/noun/etc. is related to everything else no matter how weak that relationship may be.  It may be so weak it's essentially undetectable - and this comes from the fact that the use of the words "dependent" or "indepdent" are actually misnomers - but must be used (for practicality's sake) due to the limits of current human knowledge in math/statistics.

Answer (score 2):

The answer, in my mind, is "Yes and No, and if Yes then this isn't actually interesting".

For variables with no dependency structure, the answer is no - a very high, or very low, value of a particular variable doesn't imply a very high, or very low value of another variable.

For variables with a dependency structure, the answer is often (but not always) yes. But this isn't a property of "outlier-ness", it's a property of correlation itself. What you're showing is not that "Being an outlier begets being an outlier in other areas" but that two associated variables behave exactly like associated variables should.

Answer (score 2):

I've thought about this question for a year and had an epiphany a few days ago.

In another question I left an answer to, @FrankHarrell left a separate answer that I to this day still find quite profound.

Here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/71748/28928

He says "Variable selection without penalization is invalid."

If you're attempting to analyze any set of data and determine the influence of variables on each other, then, really, the only variables you're using are the ones you have in your dataset - even if you discover that there is no relationship between certain variables.

Let's say X(sub 5) has what seems to be absolutely no relationship to your Y - so you discard it.

If you discard it, though, then you're selecting variables...incurring penalization. Additionally, if you're missing ANY variables in your dataset, you're selecting variables once again.  When I say ANY, I literally mean any and every variable in the universe.

And, well, "Variable selection without penalization is invalid."

Thus, if

**"Variable selection without penalization is invalid"** is true,

then the statement

**All variables in the universe are related/influence each other/are affected by each other/etc. must be true.**

Otherwise, penalization would not occur with variable selection.

Answer (score 1):

If I were doing a binomial test, and I had 100% of my results indicating pass until the nth sample, at which time I had one sample indicate fail, then I would say that my estimate of the binomial distribution parameters and their confidence intervals might be very different before versus after the "fail".

My binomial test is whether or not the samples belong to an expected distribution which if true gets a "pass" or whether they qualify as an outlier in which case the result is "fail".

Keywords of interest may include "zero defect sampling", and "acceptance sampling".

Reference links:

- [ASQ article](http://asq.org/quality-progress/2007/11/basic-quality/zero-defect-sampling.html)
- [Calculator](http://src.alionscience.com/toolbox/oneshotcalc.htm)