# Applying rotations to factor loadings and correlation

Tags: correlation, factor-analysis

I am currently studying factor analysis, and am told the following:

> We have a random sample $\mathbb{X} = [\mathbf{X}_1 \ \mathbf{X}_2 \ \dots \ \mathbf{X}_n] \sim \text{Sam}(\overline{\mathbf{X}}, S)$ of rank $r$. For $k \le r$, a **(sample) $k$-factor model** of $\mathbb{X}$ is
> $$\mathbb{X} = \hat{A} \mathbb{F} + \overline{\mathbf{X}} + \mathcal{R}$$
> The **common factors** $\mathbb{F} = [\mathbf{F}_1 \ \mathbf{F}_2 \ \dots \ \mathbf{F}_n]$ are $k$-dimensional random vectors which have a zero mean and identity covariance matrix.
> The **sample factor loadings** $\hat{A}$ is the $d \times k$ matrix.
> The **specific factor** is the $d \times n$ matrix $\mathcal{R}$ of zero mean random vectors and a diagonal covariance matrix $\Omega$.
> The common and specific factors are uncorrelated.

I am told that we can apply "rotations" to the factor loadings, such as "orthogonal" and "oblique" rotations. I am then told that, although the common factors and the specific factor are uncorrelated, applying these "rotations" to the factor loadings makes them correlated. Would people please explain this? Furthermore, it seems to me that we would **not** want correlation in factor analysis, since that would ruin/pollute whatever signal we are getting from performing the method in the first place, no?

Comment: No, rotating common factors (their loading matrix) does not produce correlation between common factors and unique factors. Rotations are done only within common factor space which is orthogonal to unique factors. See e.g. last pic. here https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/95106/3277

Comment: Why are we doing factor rotation, even oblique one: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/151688/3277

Comment: @ttnphns Thanks for the comments. Do the common factors themselves become correlated from rotations such as oblique rotations? I think this was the claim that was made.

Comment: Sure, oblique rotation make common factors correlated to some (usually not large) extent

Comment: @ttnphns Ok, thanks. Also, with regards to my last question, we don't want correlation between the common factors, right?

Comment: Please read the answer under my 2nd link.

Comment: @ttnphns It doesn't seem to be directly addressing my question, so I can't tell if it's saying that correlation is part of what gives factor analysis its predictive power, and so it's what we want, or whether it's not what we want because it reduces predictive power. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Rotating predictors (and factors are predictors) in their space does not change their overall, combined predictive power (that you ought to know from multiple regression). We rotate factors seeking their "better" interpretation.

Comment: @ttnphns Ok. Thanks for the clarification.