# {R Psych Package} Factor Rotation Appears to Lower Proportion of Variance Explained?

Tags: r, factor-analysis, factor-rotation

This issue arose using `R`'s `psych` package, specifically the `fa` function, but the problem is a theoretical one:

When generating the factors for a dataset, the reported "cumulative variance", i.e. the proportion of variance explained by the factors, appears to change based on the rotation method chosen. Specifically, varimax rotation appears to capture more of the overall variance than oblimin rotation.

Surely this is impossible? My understanding is that, when modelling p observed variables as manifestations of q latent variables (where q < p), a q-dimensional subspace is created within p-dimensional space. Rotation changes the basis used to describe this subspace, but doesn't change the subspace itself. In other words, rotation should not affect the proportion of variance explained, as the p-dimensional data is still being projected onto the **same** q-dimensional subspace.

Is my understanding incorrect? Or is the issue with my use of the `psych` package (perhaps, when returning the loadings generated by the `fa` function, the "Cumulative Var" row doesn't mean what I think it means?)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Oblimin is a nonorthogonal rotation. See footnote 3 here https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/151688/3277

Comment: `a q-dimensional subspace is created _within_ p-dimensional space` This is true for PCA and not for FA. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/288646/3277, https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/95106/3277.

Comment: I see... Looks as if I'll have to go back to basics on understanding factor analysis! Thanks for the resources. So "cumulative var" isn't the figure I'd want to quote to compare the difference between a 3- and 4-factor solution, I take it?

Comment: If you want to compare 3 and 4 factor solutions how much common variance is of the total variance - take the summary values from the output before an (oblique) rotation, i.e., after the factor extraction stage.